# Bootstrap HTML element not rendered with style

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been experimenting with rendering Bootstrap components within a iframe, but for some strange reason, the elements are not styled even though I have loaded the stylesheet and corresponding scripts. Why does this happen? My code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2pga8q.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.scss'],
})
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef<HTMLFrameElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.generateWebsite();
  }

  generateWebsite(): void {
    this.insertHeadElements();
    this.insertBodyElements();
  }

  insertHeadElements() {
    const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.head;
    const bootstrapStyleElement = document.createElement('link');
    bootstrapStyleElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
    bootstrapStyleElement.href =
      'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"';
    canvas.append(bootstrapStyleElement);
    const jqueryScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScriptElement.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js';
    canvas.append(jqueryScriptElement);
  }

  insertBodyElements() {
    this.insertNavbarElement();
  }

  insertNavbarElement() {
    const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body;
    const navbarElement = document.createElement('nav');
    navbarElement.className = 'navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light';
    navbarElement.innerHTML =
      '<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button><div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse"><ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"><li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a></li></ul></div>';
    canvas.append(navbarElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `"` in the style sheet path. Just remove it and it will work

```
bootstrapStyleElement.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```